# Ravendb Issues with nullables when creating Map/Reduce index

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to create an index with map/reduce using the AbstractIndexCreationTask class.
however it seems that I have issues related to nullables, inside the Map's linq query:

1. For the following let sentence I get (in studio's index view) 2 errors of
   "Nullable object must have a value":
   let isOk = Something1.HasValue && Something2.HasValue 
   (When both Somethings are of nullable int type)
2. For the following let sentence I get the following error when executing -  "System.InvalidOperationException: Could not understand query: "
   let result = isOk ? Result.result1 : (Result?)null 
   (when Result is a nullable enum - it seems that the problem occurs due to the returned casted null)

I've experienced this issues in ver 2.0, and currently on latest client version from NuGet: 2.5.2666

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of HasValue, use != null